# Is there a way to search headers that contain a certain string in SAS then apply format changes to all of them

Tags: sas

Say I have headers `NAME` (char32), `BIRTH_DATE`(best32), and `APPLICATION_DATE` (best32). Is there a way to use the `proc` procedure to search for all headers with contain "_DATE" and then change the format of all the results. So in this case we would end up with `NAME` (char32), `BIRTH_DATE`(date9), and `APPLICATION_DATE` (date9)

Comment: Are the date values SAS date values, or something like 20141006 to represent October 6, 2014? or 20002, which with with a format applied would be October 6, 2014?

Comment: @Reese they are assumed to be SAS date values or null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to solve this.  The method below uses the DICTIONARY.COLUMNS view in PROC SQL to get the columns you want.  It constructs a macro variable that can be used in PROC DATASETS to change the format.

```
data have;
format name $32. birth_date application_date best32.;
name = "x";
birth_date = "04JUL1776"d;
application_Date = today();
run;


proc sql noprint;
select name into :tochange separated by " date9. "
from dictionary.columns
where libname="WORK"
  and memname="HAVE"
  and upcase(name) like '%_DATE';
quit;

%put &tochange;

proc datasets lib=work nolist;
modify have;
    format &tochange date9.;
run;
quit;

proc print data=have;
run;
```

Comment: relatively new to SAS. What are the `libname` and `memname` values, do these represent the imported data location? also what is the `%put &tochange;` doing? Is this a temp variable keeping track of all the columns pulled from the sql search.

Comment: Open up the sashelp.vcolumn table, same as dictionary.column and you'll get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: @Reese, exactly.  LIBNAME is the library name (upcased) where your data table resides.  MEMNAME is the name of the data table.  `%put &tochange` is just printing to the log the value contained in the &tochange macro variable.